# BFILE datatype in mysql

Tags: mysql, oracle, database-design, partitioning, table

My backend is writing The Soap request within a table using a BLOB column so that I have very big tables in mysql with more of 100GB.

I need store this information out of dabase in file for example.

Oracle has the BFILE datatype this works as softlink to a file, Could I simulate the same in mysql ?

Thanks.

Comment: Sure. Store the file path (or, more generally, its URI).

Comment: But you Can't select the content using SQL

Comment: Correct you can can use something like x-sendfile and let the scalable part of your infrastructure handle it distributing the file rather than the less scalable database.

Comment: Elaborate on what you need to do with the BLOB, rather than just asking about the proposed solution.  There may well be an adequate workaround.